# How to create several objects of the same class with an infinite loop inside each

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've tried to spawn balls using onkey(spawn, "space") and it was ok. But how to spawn them using for loop?
It seems that "while True" loop inside class method doesn't allow to make iterations of "for loop" outside.

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint

w = 100
h = 100
BallList = []

sc = Screen()
sc.tracer(0)

class Ball(Turtle):
  def __init__(self, x, y, s, c):
    Turtle.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.s = s
    self.c = c
    self.color(self.c)
    self.shape("circle")
    self.penup()
    self.speed(0)
    self.setheading(self.towards(randint(-100, 100), randint(-100, 100)))

  def move(self):
    self.forward(self.s)

  def bounce(self):
    if self.xcor() > w:
      self.setheading(self.towards(-w, randint(-100, 100)))
    if self.xcor() < -w:
      self.setheading(self.towards(w, randint(-100, 100)))
    if self.ycor() > h:
      self.setheading(self.towards(randint(-100, 100), -h))
    if self.ycor() < -h:
      self.setheading(self.towards(randint(-100, 100), h))

  def loop(self):
    while True:
      self.move()
      self.bounce()
      sc.update()

for i in range(10):
  BallList.append(Ball(0, 0, 10, (0, 100, 0)))
  BallList[i].loop()
```

Comment: Can you create objects first, and then handle whatever infinite loops you have?

Comment: remove the infinite loop in the `def loop(self)` method, create your balls in a for loop, and follow it up with another infinite loop that loops through the balls and calls loop for each one of them, but the `loop` is no longer blocking

Comment: Since it appears that method `loop` does not appear to give up the CPU, you need to use multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove endless loop in your `loop` method of a `Ball` class, so that it looks like this:

```
  def loop(self):
    self.move()
    self.bounce()
    sc.update()
```

2. Create your balls first, don't try to handle them just yet:

```
for i in range(10):
  BallList.append(Ball(0, 0, 10, (0, 100, 0)))
```

3. Follow up with an endless loop to update the balls:

```
while True:
  for i in range(10):
    BallList[i].loop()
```

---

- I think it makes sense to rename `loop` method of `Ball` class, to something like `update`, as it's no longer going to be looping anything
- BallList is not a class, I think it would make better sense to rename it to `balls` instead (Note the lower case letter, to not mess up with classes)

Edit: 
I think having `sc.update()` call inside Ball-s `loop` method is probably redundant. It is probably enough to call that `sc.update()` thing once, after all the balls were recalculated, like this:

```
while True:
  for i in range(10):
    BallList[i].loop()
  sc.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

An infinite `while True:` loop has no business in an event-driven environment like turtle, neither inside an object class nor outside one.  Let's replace it by giving each ball it's own timer event (for maximum flexibility):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 400

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position, step, color):
        super().__init__(shape='circle')

        self.step = step

        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(position)
        self.setheading(randint(1, 360))

        self.loop()

    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.step)

    def bounce(self):
        x, y = self.position()

        if x > WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2:
            self.setheading(self.towards(-WIDTH/2, randint(CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE)))
        elif x < CURSOR_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2:
            self.setheading(self.towards(WIDTH/2, randint(CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE)))
        elif y > HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2:
            self.setheading(self.towards(randint(CURSOR_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2), -HEIGHT/2))
        elif y < CURSOR_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2:
            self.setheading(self.towards(randint(CURSOR_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE/2), HEIGHT/2))

    def loop(self):
        self.move()
        self.bounce()
        screen.update()

        screen.ontimer(self.loop, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.colormode(255)
screen.tracer(0)

for _ in range(10):
    Ball((0, 0), 10, (0, 100, 0))

screen.mainloop()
```

Other issues encountered: you're using the wrong color specification for the default `colormode()`; the variables `self.x` and `self.y` are never used; avoid single letter variable names; I switched to Python 3 style superclass initialization, it's not clear what version you're using; avoid wildcard imports; the `self.setheading()` call in `__init__` is unnecessarily complicated; the `if` statements in `bounce()` aren't completely independent;